# why constructor is not enough to run thymleaf template?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

today i was trying to fix an error in a simple code, after searching i find out that to fix the error you need to add Getters and Setters in model, let me post the code first without getters and setters to show you exactly whats going on.

User Model code

```
package com.fsb.app.web.model;

public class User 
{
    
    private String userName;
    private String role;

    public User(String userName, String role) 
    {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

RoleController Controller Code

```
package com.fsb.app.web.controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.fsb.app.web.model.User;

@Controller
public class RoleController 
{
    User user = new User("Administrator", "admin");
    @RequestMapping("/switchsample")
    public String switchSample(Model model) 
    {
    
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "switchsample";
    }

}
```

and last and not least my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>th:witch/th:case</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>th:witch/th:case</h1>
      <h4 th:text="${user.userName}"></h4>
      <div th:switch="${user.role}">
         <div th:case="'admin'">User is an administrator</div>
         <div th:case="'manager'">User is a manager</div>
         <div th:case="'staff'">User is a staff</div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

i ge the following error
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfvGh.png)

> sometimes question can sound stupid simply because they are far too broad

but if i add the setters and getters the error got fixed and i get expected result, my question is not how to fix the problem cause its already been fixed the question is i created a constructor and filled that constructor in controller so user Variable should have userName as "Administrator" and role as "Admin" why do i need getters and setters ? i really didnt use them in controller
if my question seems dumb im sorry im learning java and spring at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf uses [OGNL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/developer-guide.html) expressions. This is a level of abstraction so that you can build powerful expressions (see [thymeleaf documentation on Variables](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#variables).

Any way you have declared your instance variables as private - which is good for encapsulation, however, if they have a private scope how would Thymeleaf access them?